# proftpd trouble with File upload Permissions

Tags: ftp, permissions, proftpd

I am hosting some servers for friends & want to give them a possibilty to upload / edit / delete files with FTP.

So, I created some users, but everytime, they try to upload something, it gets uploaded, but the file permission is '0000'. How do I change this?

They also cant create a new file or folder...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[umask](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Umask.html) is used to set permissions on newly uploaded files.

The proftpd daemon always starts with a base-mode of 0666 when creating files.  umask then further reduces the access rights as follows:

```
new file mode = base-mode - umask
```

For example, with a umask of 0066 a newly uploaded file would have 0600 (rw-------) permissions:

```
0600 = 0666 - 0066
```

So check or remove your umask settings.